# Oracle DB upgrade issue - view, audits/logs that hold info

Tags: logging, oracle-database

Is there a way in Oracle DB (regardless of version) to retrieve info for a version upgrade, and by means of views or traces/logs?

For example: the timestamp it took place, prior version of the database and current-upgraded version?

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to look in the DBA_AUDIT tables (if auditing is turned on) to see when the system tables and such were updated during the upgrade. Other than that, I don't know of any place that it would store previous version information and timestamps as to when that changed.

You could take a look at the Oracle binaries on the actual server to see how old they are. This would give you somewhat of a timestamp as to when they were upgraded. It depends on what you're looking to find; last upgrade, date of previous upgrades, etc...